# Restful web service giving error of Response does not contain any data

Tags: rest, symfony

I am writing a Restful web service in symfony2. Same service is working fine on the localhost returning the response data but not on the server. 
I `print_r()` the response variable and it is showing the data array.

```
    $user = new Users();

        $user->setUsername($paramFetcher->get('email'));
        $password = $paramFetcher->get('password');
        $user->setUserType('business');
        if($password==""){

            $user->setPassword(rand(0,1000));

        }else{

            $user->setPassword($password);
        }

    $data['UserDetails']['id'] = $user->getId();
    $data['UserDetails']['username'] = $user->getUsername();
    $data['UserDetails']['password'] = $user->getPassword();
    $data['UserDetails']['usertype'] = $user->getUserType();


    $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        //print_r($data); print_r($buss); 
    $response[]=array("code"=>200,"message"=>"success","data"=>$data);
```

Please guide

Comment: Can you show the full error message? Is it :"The controller must return a response (null given)"? Also if it is working locally but not on a live server then have you made sure you have cleared the cache on the live server using the --env=prod parameter?

Comment: the full error message was this only `response does not contain any data`. and it worked with cache clearing thanx

Answer (score 0):

If this code is inside a controller then your function will need to return a response. If you want to output json then you need to return a JsonResponse object:

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($response);
```

Comment: yes this is inside a controller function. But other functions in the same controller are working fine and returning the correct response, only this function has this problem